# Dividing a series containing datetime by a series containing an integer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series s1 which is of type datetime and has a time which represents a range between a start time and an end time - typical values are 7 days, 4 hours 5 mins etc. I have series s2 which contains integers for the number of events that happened in that time range.

I want to calculate the event frequency by:

> event_freq = s1 / s2

I get the error:

> cannot operate on a series with out a rhs of a series/ndarray of type datetime64[ns] or a timedelta

Whats the best way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

EXAMPLE of s1 is:

```
some_id

1          2012-09-02 09:18:40
3          2012-04-02 09:36:39
4          2012-02-02 09:58:02
5          2013-02-09 14:31:52
6          2012-01-09 12:59:20
```

EXAMPLE of s2 is:

```
some_id
1           3
3           1
4           1
5           2
6           1
8           1
10          3
12          2
```

Comment: Could you give an example of s1 and s2 which demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Hey Andy, just added - thanks for the tip.

Comment: s1 in a Series of dates, not sure it makes sense to divide that by an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might possibly be a bug but what works is to operate on the underlying numpy array like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series

startdate = Series(pd.date_range('2013-01-01', '2013-01-03'))
enddate = Series(pd.date_range('2013-03-01', '2013-03-03'))

s1 = enddate - startdate
s2 = Series([2, 3, 4])

event_freq = Series(s1.values / s2)
```

Here are the Series:

```
>>> s1
0   59 days, 00:00:00
1   59 days, 00:00:00
2   59 days, 00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

>>> s2
0    2
1    3
2    4
dtype: int64

>>> event_freq
0   29 days, 12:00:00
1   19 days, 16:00:00
2   14 days, 18:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: this is currently not implemented mainly because support in numpy < 1.7 doesn't work, but not too hard to do: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4521